# Nonattacking configurations of bishops on squares of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

It is known that the number of possible configurations of $i$ bishops on squares of the same color of an $n\times n$ chessboard for even $n$ is given by:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\frac{(-1)^j{n-i-1\choose j}(n-i-j)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(n-i-j+1)^\frac{n}{2}}{(n-i-1)!}$$

But how does one derive/obtain this formula?

Answer (score 2):

This question [has been asked on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54677/how-to-place-k-bishops-on-an-nxn-chessboard). According to the update,

> an explicit formula for $B_k(n)$ as a triple sum was given

That answer links to the [full paper](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/zaslav/Tpapers/bishops.slides.20100729.pdf), but your general formula does not appear.

Comment: @ruadan That's because it's not the same as your formula. It's a triple sum; yours is not. I'm not sure where you found yours ... ?